# Extracting digits from string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, string, regular-expression

I have a string field that I want to extract only the digits example: 1,500 m2 -> 1500

[image: example]

I've tried with `regexp_substr("location", '(\\d*)')` to remove all after the blank space, but I need also the ones that have a comma to only extract the digits, the first two rows work fine for me, but the two after doesn't (`1,500 M2` and `1,456 m2`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another regex expression to use is the following:

```
 regexp_substr("FieldName",'\\d,+\\d+|\\d+')
```

Substitute `"FieldName"` with the name of the field that you want to extract the digits from. `"descriptio"` in your case.

The above will extract digits with comma or digits without comma.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!, this worked, but I realized I had blank spaces as well besides commas, is there an expression to solve that too?

Comment: @JuanMillan I have not try this but you can give it a try: `regexp_substr("FieldName",'\\d , \\d+|\\d,+\\d+|\\d+')`

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit old-fashion approach but also gives a desired output using the follwoing expression

```py
to_int(replace(left("text", regexp_match("text",' ') - 1), ',', ''))
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way to remove 1) the string `'M2'` plus 2) all characters except numbers is this epression. Like this, you remove commas, letters, all whitespaces etc., but keep all number (except the `2` in `M2`):

```
regexp_replace (Elev,'(M2|[^0-9])','')
```

---

*To match uppercase `M2` as well as lowercase `m2`, instead of  `(M2|` use `(M|m)2|`:*

*`regexp_replace (Elev,'((M|m)2|[^0-9])','')`*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the regular expression provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917217/7144368).

```
regexp_substr( "location", '\b\d[\d,.]*\b' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more general solution:

```
regexp_replace("location",'\\b(\\d+)[.,]?(\\d*)\\b.+','\\1\\2')
```

... and many other regex here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional

Comment: Although a valid regular expression, it will not work as-is with [regex_replace - QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) because "Backslash characters must be double escaped...."

Comment: @bixb0012 you are absolutely right… I changed my answer