# Matching specific word character in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

With the graphical modeller, I try to decode a set of codes:

[image]

Since the code `'_zie'` is also contained in the code `'_p_zie'`, I get two matches for `'_p_zie'`.

How can I get two specific Word characters out of them, so that I only get the word `'Mauer'` for `'_zie'` and the word `'Pfeiler'` for `'_p_zie'`?

Comment: Have you tried to use the digits? For example you could use something like regexp_match("bef_nr", '[^0-9]_zie') - I haven't tested this. Here is an example - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354277/extracting-digits-from-string-in-qgis

Comment: With your expression QGIS sets no value for '_zie' and value 'Mauer' for '_p_zie'. I think the hole thing is about to define the codes as a contiguous word character.

Comment: Your expression for '_p_zie' should only return 'Pfeiler'. Does this happen? Your return for '_zie' should return both 'Mauer' and 'Pfeiler', does this happen? It is hard to know what is happening because you are calling the column 'bef_nr' but there are no letters in the column 'bef_nr'...is the first screenshot the input or output? Can you provide a reproducible copy of the data?

Comment: Sorry. The first screenshot shows the output. But in the first column 'Bef_nr Check' you can see the input. The result is exactly the vice versa of what you said: '_p_zie' return both 'Mauer' and 'Pfeiler'. '_zie' return only  'Mauer'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues.

First, `case` returns when there is a match, but because you are not using a single `case` statement with multiple `where`, but rather you are concatenating multiple `case` having a single `where`, a value of `_p_zie` will always get assigned both codes --> use a single `case`

Then, with a single `case`, you must order the conditions so the most restrictive ones are evaluated first --> evaluate `_p_zie` before `_zie`

And at last, for efficiency only, there is no need for a regex, a cheaper `right` would do the job.

```
CASE 
  WHEN right("bef_nr",2)='_s' THEN 'Schicht'
  WHEN right("bef_nr",6)='_p_zie' THEN 'Pfeiler'
  WHEN right("bef_nr",4)='_zie' THEN 'Mauer'
  ELSE 'unknown'
END
```

[image]

**Edit**

To decode multiple tokens, you can use `regexp_match` as you have done, but then you can specify that a number (`\\d`) is expected before `_zie`.

```
...
regexp_match("bef_nr",'\\d_zie')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you JGH. Good answer! But please look at the screenshot. The first column shows the input, while the other columns show the output. In the third row of the first column there are two codes. That's why I chose multiple cases, because with only one case with multiple where one code was returned only. I think that a simple right is therefore problematic. Would there be a solution for this?

Comment: @Janko see edit for how to tweak the regex then

Comment: @ JGH this works fine. Thank you so much!!